# Spring boot:Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

Faz pouco tempo que estou usando Spring.
Alterei o nome do pacote controller e a aplicação não quer mais rodar.
[image: erro no aparecendo no console]

[image: antes estava trajes.trajes]

Na segunda imagem em vermelho sublinhado estava trajes.trajes o nome do pacote e alterei para trajes.controller.O que eu fiz de errado?

Answer (score 3):

Achei o meu próprio erro,quando eu fui refatorar eu não renomeei corretamente.Eu dei rename directory e não rename package.O certo é rename package.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

O problema está na classe TrajesApplication.

Você precisa movê-la para a pasta com\sistema\trajes\trajes

Veja que não existe mais esse pacote: com.sistema.trajes.trates, seu arquivo TrajesApplication estava lá, e você moveu para dentro do pacote Controller.

E é disso que o Intelij está reclamando